# How to enable softkeys on a rooted phone with capacitive buttons?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, softkey

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 tablet and the capacitive buttons are extremely annoying - I keep pressing them accidentally all the time while holding the tablet in landscape orientation. The tablet is running Android 7.0 and is rooted with TWRP/SuperSU.

It's easy to disable the physical buttons through [various apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synteticdreams.hbbegone), but how can I enable the **native** softkeys? There are various apps that simulate the software buttons in the Play Store, but they're all glitchy.

I've tried adding *qemu.hw.mainkeys=0* to the *build.prop* file, but after doing that the tablet gets stuck at the black screen when rebooting.

Comment: The getting stuck problem is probably because the stock kernel has detection for `/system` modification.

Comment: @AndyYan any way to override that?

Comment: Custom kernels/ROMs, though that might be *far* off what you expected to get something this simple. Perhaps I'm wrong and there is a simpler approach - wait for others to put forward alternatives. // As for non-native solution, LMT Launcher had always worked well for me, and doesn't occupy a bar of screen space.